# How do I alter the URL?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, jsp, url

I'm currently working on a big web application for a company and we are about 4 months in, but we have a harmless(but annoying) problem that we have just left because we didn't time to change it.

The way we setup our MVC is leaving us with the Servlet being stacked one after the other endless amounts of times on the URL so if we had a Servlet named "ControllerServlet" and I did something on the website I would get a result such as this the first time.

WebsiteXXXXXXX.com/XXX/**ControllerServlet**XXXX

And the next time I were to do something everything will work fine, but the URL will stack the ControllerServlet Path like this..

WebsiteXXXXXXX.com/XXX**/ControllerServlet/ControllerServlet/**XXXX

WebsiteXXXXXXX.com/XXX**/ControllerServlet/ControllerServlet/ControllerServlet/**XXXX

and so on....

Although it is working perfectly fine, something is obviously not right.

I imagine this is an easy fix, but could really use somebodies help.

Thanks alot

Comment: In your JSP, look at the "target" parameter of each form, and report back, please?

Comment: In our Form Parameters we are using the format ControllerServlet/action and reading the action off of the path in the Servlet. 

From there we are handling it like a typical Model 2 MVC and doing the business and redirecting to the View.

The problem is at the point we are reading the action off of the path, the URL has already stacked the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a context-relative URL in the form action is used (i.e. an URL without a domain part and without a leading slash `/`), then it is relative to the last context of the current request URL.

When a page which is requested by `http://example.com/webapp/ControllerServlet` and contains the following form action:

```
<form action="ControllerServlet/action">
```

Then the absolute action URL will be `http://example.com/webapp/ControllerServlet/ControllerServlet/action`. To fix this, you need to ensure that the form action URL is in a correct manner relative to the request URL. For a page which is requested by `http://example.com/webapp/ControllerServlet/action` there are several ways, depending on the ways how you *can* request the same page.

Either

```
<form action="action">
```

..which is relative to the *last* context in the request URL, or

```
<form action="/webapp/ControllerServlet/action">
```

..which is relative to the domain root, or

```
<form action="../ControllerServlet/action">
```

..which is relative to the context *before* the last context in the URL (it will effectively remove `/ControllerServlet` from the current request URL and append it again -a bit pointless indeed, but useful if you have more servlets in the context), or

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ControllerServlet/action">
```

..which is relative to the domain root (useful when you don't want to hardcode the webapp's context path), or

```
<head>
    <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <form action="ControllerServlet/action">
    ...
</body>
```

..which would apply to all links and forms.

All of above will point to `http://example.com/webapp/ControllerServlet/action`.

Comment: Im def going to go try to fix this, i think I may have made alot of really simple errors. Thanks Alot!